# Maximising a discrete valued probability function

Tags: statistics, discrete-optimization

The problem I am attempting to solve is [image]

the maximising bit. The solution talks about how we should look at adjacent terms for when $p_N≈ p_{N-1} $. However, how do I know that I am not finding a minimum or another maximum? Or ever further, why does this point need to have close points near it?

Comment: Did you look at $p_N-p_{N-1}$ or $\frac{p_N}{p_{N-1}}$?  (I would suggest the latter)  What would you find?

Comment: Hi, I think i know where you are getting at, I thought for a while after I posted this question and I figured it out. The only reason I have left the question is for the first part. Do we know it is the only maximum or if we find that $\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}=1}$ has $n$ that are more than one faraway then we have $n$ many maximums?

Comment: $\frac{p_N}{p_{N-1}}$ should only switch from above $1$ to below $1$ once as $N$ increases